# How to make (in game)(in Python) a loop that will print a string from a list/tuple?

Tags: loops, random

I am currently working on a game and can't figure out how to every time I die, I can display a hint that will change each time randomly

> > LOOP = random.choice
> >     Hints = ("a", "b", "c", "d") #this will be changed but for now it will work
> >     rand_Hints = LOOP(Hints)

Comment: It looks like your array addressing is backwards. Shouldn't it be `Hints(LOOP)`?

Comment: No I don't think so.
Reminder it is coded in Python.